# Are these two definitions of an android task related to each other or they are completely unrelated?

Tags: android

I came across two definitions of a task that made me little confused.
It's mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) that **A task is a collection of activities that users interact with when performing a certain job.** But [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable), **One or more Runnable objects that perform a particular operation are sometimes called a task.**

So, my question is are these two definitions of an android task related to each other or they are completely unrelated? I'm sorry for this naive question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are unrelated. "Task" is a fairly generic noun, and we use it for a lot of different things in computer programming.

Comment: Yeah! they are unrelated.